# T-SQL RETURN is not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Problem with My T-SQL to see if the item EXISTS on the table but I have the error message

> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 A RETURN statement with a return
>   value cannot be used in this context. Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line
>   4 A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this
>   context.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(timesheetID)
FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
WHERE userID ='12'  AND CONVERT(date, startTimeStamp)=CONVERT(date, getdate())) 
    RETURN 1
else
RETURN 0
```

The whole code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTimesheetIsEXISTS_forUser]  @UserID uniqueidentifier

AS 
BEGIN    
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from   
-- interfering with SELECT statements.  SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(timesheetID) FROM 
 [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry] 
 WHERE userID
  ='3fd971f7-e6e8-40fe-a90d-a7c9df8bf7b5'  
 AND CONVERT(date, startTimeStamp)=CONVERT(date, getdate()))



  RETURN 1 
else 
 RETURN 0 
END
```

Comment: Did you check this error message on the net? Where do you want to use it? In a function or stored procedure? Post the whole code pls

Comment: In general return should only be used to show success or failure. You should use an output paraemter to send information or a select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTimesheetIsEXISTS_forUser]  @UserID uniqueidentifier

AS 
BEGIN   

SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(timesheetID) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isExists
    FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
    WHERE userID = @UserID  AND CONVERT(date, startTimeStamp)=
     CONVERT(date, getdate())

END
```

Answer (score 6):

Return works inside a stored procedure/user defined functions.

Simple tsql is just batch of commands. I guess you want to write SELECT instead of RETURN.

Answer (score 3):

You can only call `return` in stored procedures and functions. I'm assuming this isn't either.

Comment: Not quite true - you can use return outside of a procedure, but not with an agrument to be returned.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTimesheetIsEXISTS_forUser]

It is a precedure